# Are questions about TV commercials on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, asking-questions

Are questions about television commercials considered on-topic?  More specifically, I'm referring to:

- Production methods applied to commercials, and how they differ from those used in TV programs or movies
- Practices employed in television advertising (e.g. why I sometimes see the same ad twice in a row)
- Particular advertising campaigns (e.g. why there are so many car commercials on American television)
- How ads affect the structure of TV programs (how ad slots are allocated)

Or any others that come to mind.

Comment: We used to have an [advertising] tag, but it was removed because basically we don't have many questions that are purely about advertising/commercials.  They are such a core part of the viewing experience of TV over the years its hard to view them as automatically off topic, but I'm not sure they would get a very good welcome here.

Comment: The only rule we have against them that I'm aware of is that ID questions can not be about commercials... Whether we're the best audience for some of those questions is debatable...

Comment: @Catija - agreed, but that question and associated answer are very old.  This question is has much better examples of advertising questions.

Comment: Examples: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51586/when-a-tv-commercial-shows-for-a-split-second-then-cuts-off-what-is-happening http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31313/are-movie-stars-typically-forbidden-from-appearing-in-future-commercials-resembl?s=10|0.4087 http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/30129/can-someone-explain-the-acura-i-sell-cars-you-sell-you-ads

Comment: I think I'm going to close this, and copy a lot of the examples into the older question - since I think the answer still stands.

Comment: @iandotkelly or I can answer this one. Your call.

Comment: @Catija - feel free to improve or add an alternative answer to the duplicate.  I think the answer basically still stands, "yes they are on topic, no we don't get a lot of them here."